# Permutation matrix with respect to F_p automorphisms

Tags: nt.number-theory, linear-algebra

Let $p$ be an odd prime at least $5$. Let $a_1, \dots, a_{p-1}$ be positive integers such that
$a_i=i+p\cdot b_i$ for some integer $b_i$ for each $i$.

Let $\sigma_k$ be an automorphism on $\{1, 2, \dots, p-1 \}$ sending $i$ to $ik \pmod p$ and $\delta_k$ is the inverse of $\sigma_k$.
(So, $\sigma_1$ is the identity.)

Let $M$ be a square matrix of size $p-1$ whose $ij$-th entry is $a_{\delta_i(j)}$. (So, its first row is $(a_1, a_2, \dots, a_{p-1})$.) I think this matrix is a type of permutation matrix given by an automorphism on the finite field of $p$ elements.
Since $b_i+b_{p-i}=b_j+b_{p-j}$ for all $i\neq j$, then surely this matrix is not invertible.
However, since the permutation matrix is invertible, I wonder the same is true for $M$ under the assumption that $b_i+b_{p-i}=b_j+b_{p-j}$ for some $i \neq j$. Here is my question.

**Is M invertible if $b_i+b_{p-i}=b_j+b_{p-j}$ for some $i\neq j$?**

For instance, take $p=5$ and $a_1=1, a_2=2, a_3=3$ and $a_4=9$. Then, we have
$$
M=\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
1 & 2 & 3 & 9 \\
3 & 1 & 9 & 2 \\
2 & 9 & 1 & 3 \\
9 & 3 & 2 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}\right).
$$
By direct computation, we find
$$
195 \times M^{-1}=\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
1 & -5 & -8 & 25 \\
-8 & 1 & 25 & -5 \\
-5 & 25 & 1 & -8 \\ 
25 & -8 & -5 & 1 \\
\end{array}\right).
$$

Another example is $p=7$ and
$$
M=\left(\begin{array}{cccccc}
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 13 \\
4 & 1 & 5& 2 & 13 & 3 \\
5 & 3 & 1 & 13 & 4 & 2\\
2 & 4 & 13 & 1 & 3 & 5\\
3 & 13 & 2 & 5 & 1 & 4\\
13 & 5& 4 & 3 & 2 & 1\\
\end{array}\right).
$$
By direct computation, we find
$$
2^3 \times 7 \times 19 \times M^{-1}=\left(\begin{array}{cccccc}
 15 & -9 &-13 &-25& -29 & 99 \\
-25 & 15 &-29 & -9 & 99& -13\\
-29 &-13 & 15  &99& -25 & -9\\
-9 &-25 & 99 & 15& -13& -29\\
-13  &99 & -9 &-29 & 15& -25\\
99 &-29 &-25 &-13 & -9 & 15\\
\end{array}\right).
$$

Note that if $M^{-1}$ exists and if we write its first column by $(v_1, v_2, \dots, v_{p-1})$ then the $ij$-th entry of $M^{-1}$ is $v_{\delta_j(i)}$.

Comment: When $p=5$, then the determinant is 
$$
((a_1+a_4)^2-(a_2+a_3)^2)(a_1-a_4)^2(a_2-a_3)^2.
$$
Thus, at least we need more conditions like $a_i\neq a_{p-i}$.